# How to make visible my app in the Salesforce platform

Tags: salesfoce

I'm lost

I created a form in the developer console, and I need to make it visible from the Salesforce platform. But I can't find how to do it

thanks!!

Comment: Is the form a VF pages or Aura component?

Comment: @manjit5190  <> Aura component

Comment: Can someone help me?? Please

Comment: Erik have ykubwne through this document. This lists our the options for exposing the Aura components on the UI https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1.htm

Comment: @manjit5190  thanks!!